# Specifying a non-earth / unknown CRS

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, pyqgis

Occasional requirement to visualise arbitrary vector data in QGIS, adding features from Python.
[understanding that they cannot be overlayed with any data on known projections]

How can I specify Unknown / non-earth CRS for the layer?
crs = QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem(??)

Answer (score 1):

From the QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem [documentation](https://qgis.org/api/classQgsCoordinateReferenceSystem.html) it accepts WKT text for the CRS definition.

The Well-Known Text format supports a keyword for defining 'local' ungeoreferenced coordinate systems 'LOCAL_CS'.  See geotools documentation [here](https://docs.geotools.org/stable/javadocs/org/opengis/referencing/doc-files/WKT.html).

Therefore you could try the following:

```
'LOCAL_CS["yourCS", UNIT["METER",1]]'
```

Disclaimer: untested by myself in QGIS.